# Dbt: Adding query-comment in dbt_project.yml does not add query comments in compiled code

Tags: dbt

I've added in dbt_project.yml the following code:

```
query-comment:
    comment: 'run by {{ target.user }} in dbt'
```

but after running the models in the compiled code in the target folder I do not see the comment which is supposed to be there.

I've tried to test the query-comment and using dbt run or dbt compile but in the target folder I do not see the comment. I am using a local postgres database. Models all run successfully but without comments in the compiled SQL.

Comment: Have you tried indenting `comment`, as the docs propose? https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/project-configs/query-comment

Comment: I have edited the question. Also for the record this does not work either:

query-comment: 'run by {{ target.user }} in dbt'

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Snowflake, you'll need to add the `append:true` option. With this option, dbt will append the comment at the end of the query (Snowflake automatically removes any comments that are at the beginning of the query)